# what is the media player uid in symbian^3 (N8 device)

Tags: c++, qt, symbian

in my application,i just wanna open a url contain media,e.g. http://www.test.com/test.mp3,or rstp://www.test.com/test.3gp,so i need the symbian embeded media player's uid to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use for showing links:

```
_LIT( KTestUrlPrefix,"4 " );
HBufC* parameter = HBufC::NewLC( KTestUrlPrefix().Length() + aLink.Length() );
parameter->Des().Copy( KTestUrlPrefix );
parameter->Des().Append( aLink );
if(iLauncher)
{
    delete iLauncher;
    iLauncher = NULL;
}
iLauncher = CBrowserLauncher::NewL();
iLauncher->LaunchBrowserEmbeddedL( *parameter, NULL, NULL, iOverriddenSettings );
CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy();

_LOGENTRY("web ad->");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the content type of the URL, you can discover the UID of the right application and launch it as detailed [here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001421_-_Opening_an_HTML_link_in_the_web_browser).

There are other alternatives:

- [`CVideoPlayerUtility`](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Nokia_Symbian3_Developers_Library/GUID-0F1F8AC6-B99F-3274-A785-9977197AF762.html?resultof=%22%43%56%69%64%65%6f%50%6c%61%79%65%72%55%74%69%6c%69%74%79%22%20%22%63%76%69%64%65%6f%70%6c%61%79%65%72%75%74%69%6c%22%20) and [`CAudioPlayerUtility`](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Nokia_Symbian3_Developers_Library/GUID-778D24B5-A68E-3C91-B66A-69007FBA4791.html?resultof=%22%63%6d%64%61%61%75%64%69%6f%70%6c%61%79%65%72%75%74%69%6c%69%74%79%22%20%22%63%6d%64%61%61%75%64%69%6f%70%6c%61%79%65%72%75%74%69%6c%22%20--). Both have `OpenUrl()` methods.
- Use the streaming classes directly (`CMdaAudioOutStream` and friends)

.. and there are other methods too.
That all said, if you are targeting Symbian^3 onwards, you might be better off developing in QT - Symbian C++ can very much considered 'deprecated' for app development.